# Vue js Laravel Sweet Alert Form Submit on confirm

Tags: laravel, vue.js, sweetalert

I have a form in Laravel /VueJS with multiple submit buttons. I wrote a code for confirm on submit with input button.
After Sweet Alert confirm, the form does not get submitted, as there is event.preventDefault().
Can anyone help me on what I need to do ?

```
<template>
  
    <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 cell">
    
        <input type="submit" name="submit" v-on:click="showAlertConfirm()"></input>
        
    </div>
  
</template>
     
<script>
       
  export default {
    methods: {
        showAlert(){
            this.$swal('Hello Vue world Test!!!');
        },
        showAlertConfirm()
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            var form = $('input[name="submit"]').closest("form");
            console.log('form');
            console.log(form);
            this.$swal.fire({
              title: 'Are you sure you want to submit?',
              text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
              type: 'warning',
              showCancelButton: true,
              confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
              cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
              confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
            }).then((result) => {
                      console.log(result);     
                      if (result.isConfirmed==true) {
                        //this does not work
                        form.submit();
                                                
                        this.$swal.fire(
                          'Submitted!',
                          'Your file has been submitted.',
                          'success')              
                      }
                      
                })
        },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: where did you declare the `form` variable?

Comment: It is after event.PreventDefault(). The form variable contains all info of the form.